# Bookmarklet - What can server see

Tags: bookmarklet

Yesterday I was reading about this bookmarklet [Bookmarklet to submit page source to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097416/bookmarklet-to-submit-page-source-to-form)

It takes the sourcecode from a site, at sent it to anoter side.

If I run it on site "A" and send the sourcecode to site "B", can site "A", then see that?

Comment: I don't see why it would since it just running the code in the browser and sending the source code to site "B"